# Application of inverse function theorem for several variable functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be continuously differentiable, and assume $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Also for any compact $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact. prove $f$ is onto.

My Work:

This is an application of inverse function theorem because it satisfies the hypothesis of this thoerem. So $A=f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, $A^c$ is closed. Afterwards I was stuck. please give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is indeed locally a homeomorphism, so an open map. Now use that the inverse compactness condition shows that $f$ is also closed and so has a closed image (and use connectedness of $f[\mathbb{R}^2]$ to finish). So suppose $f(x_n) \in f[\mathbb{R}^2]$ and $f(x_n) \rightarrow y$ (we need to show $y$ is in the image too). Then $K = \{f(x_n) : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{y\}$ is compact...